# Proof for Limit law for Products - bounds

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I've been trying to prove the limit law for products. I found the hint in 
 this [Proof of the Product Limit Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168905/proof-of-the-product-limit-law) to be helpful but am still stuck.

I set $$\epsilon>0$$
And I let 
$$0<|x-a|<\delta_1->|f(x)-L|<\epsilon/2$$
and 
$$0<|x-a|<\delta_2->|g(x)-M|<\epsilon/2$$

Then $$|f(x)g(x)-L*M|=|f(x)g(x)-Mf(x)-Lg(x)+Mf(x)+Lg(x)-L*M|\leq |g(x)||f(x)-L|+|L||g(x)-M|$$

But now I'm stuck. How do I bound the |g(x)| and the |L| in the final expression? i.e. $$|g(x)||f(x)-L|+|L||g(x)-M|$$

I know that I'd get $$|f(x)-L|+|g(x)-M|< (\epsilon/2) + (\epsilon/2) = \epsilon$$ if it weren't for L and g(x).

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that $|L|$ is just a constant.  So if you need $|L||g(x)-M|$ to be small, you can choose $|g(x)-M|$ to be small enough that the multiplication by $|L|$ doesn't make it too large.  You chose to make $|g(x)-M|<\epsilon/2$, but that was pretty arbitrary.  What would be a better choice, if you want $|L||g(x)-M|$ to be small?

For handling the $|g(x)|$, you can't quite do the same thing since it's not a constant.  But, can you bound $|g(x)|$ by some constant, independent of $x$ (as long as $x$ is near $a$, since that's all you care about for the limit)?

Comment: Ah thanks that helps. So, I could for instance say $$|g(x)-M|<1$$ then this would bound the M? In terms of bounding g(x), what do you mean by bounding it with some constant? Can we do that when g(x) is one of the functions involved in the limit?